# Let $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $N \geq 3$ and $q > 1$. Show that $\frac{1}{2^*} - \frac{2}{N(q-1) - 1} < 0 \iff q < 2^*$.

Tags: solution-verification

Let $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $N \geq 3$, $q > 1$ and $2^* := \frac{2N}{N - 2}$. Show that $\frac{1}{2^*} - \frac{2}{N(q-1) - 1} < 0 \iff q < 2^*$.

I would like to know how to prove the statement above. I tried to prove it, but I couldn't.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

$(\Longrightarrow)$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2^*} < \frac{2}{N(q-1) - 1} &\Longrightarrow \frac{N(q-1) - 1}{2} < 2^*\\
&\Longrightarrow q - 2 \overset{(N > 2)}{<} \frac{N(q-1) - N}{2} \overset{(N > 1)}{<} \frac{N(q-1) - 1}{2} < 2^*
\end{align}$$

$(\Longleftarrow)$

$$\begin{align}
0 < q - 1 < q < 2^* &\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2^*} < \frac{1}{q - 1}\\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{2}{2^*N} < \frac{2}{N(q-1)} < \frac{2}{N(q-1) - 1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that
$$\frac{N-2}{2N}-\frac{2}{N(q-1)-1}<0$$
if and only if
$$q<\frac{2N}{N-2}$$
Is this correct? I would highly recommend never using a number as a variable, as it just looks incredibly confusing.

Anyways, lets just play around with the first equality and try to get the second one;

$$\frac{N-2}{2N}-\frac{2}{N(q-1)-1}<0$$
$$\frac{N-2}{2N}<\frac{2}{N(q-1)-1}$$
since $N-2$ is positive, we can get
$$\frac{N(q-1)-1}{2}<\frac{2N}{N-2}$$
$$q<\frac{4}{N-2}+2$$
$$q<\frac{4+2(N-2)}{N-2}$$
$$q<\frac{2N}{N-2}$$

which is exactly what we want, except for one small problem, in step 2 we assumed both sides of the equation were positive. The only place where this is an issue is that $N(q-1)-1$ might be negative. I think it isn't too difficult to argue why we know $q$ cannot be negative, Although the final result should be $1<q<2^*$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I forgot to put the hypothesis that $q > 1$. I have a question about your solution. Did you conclude that $q < \frac{4}{N - 2} + 2$ from $q < \frac{4}{N - 2} + \frac{1}{N} + 1 < \frac{4}{N - 2} + 2$ once that $N \geq 3$? Because from $\frac{N (q - 1) - 1}{2} < \frac{2N}{N - 2}$ you obtain that $q < \frac{4}{N - 2} + \frac{1}{N} + 1$. In that case, I can't do the work backwards to prove the reciprocal of the statement. Do you have an idea about how can I prove the reciprocal?

Comment: Every single step works the exact same way in both directions. Just keep track of where things need to be positive in order to not flip the inequality.